# Mac OS VirtualBox Appliance for Ubuntu 12.04 for purchase?

Tags: virtualbox, mac, virtualization

Is there a Mac OS VirtualBox Appliance for Ubuntu that one can purchase? Specifically, I have the 64 bit 12.04 version that would act as a host.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, given that it's illegal to run Mac OS X on non-Apple-labeled hardware, per section 2 of the [License Agreement](http://store.apple.com/Catalog/US/Images/MacOSX.htm):

> "This License allows you to install and use one copy of the Apple
>   Software on a single Apple-labeled computer at a time."

You probably already have a Mac, and thus OS X, which you can run with [raw disk access](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk).

Moreover, VirtualBox OS X support [is experimental](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html) and [has serious issues](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html#KnownProblems).